# Putting app, controllers & services in separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to move angular code into separate files before the project grows too big.

I tried moving the `app`, `controllers` and `services` into separate files but the errors stopped referencing points in the code (or they were too generic).

I have decided to put the file contents in on big `<script>` tag so I can work through the errors and get it working. Unfortunately I have come across [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=protonApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.1%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dapp.controllers%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.4.1%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253D%252524scope%2526p1%253DError%25253A%252520%25255B%252524injector%25253Anomod%25255D%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Ferrors.angularjs.org%25252F1.4.1%25252F%252524injector%25252Fnomod%25253Fp0%25253D%25252524scope%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520Error%252520(native)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A6%25253A416%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A23%25253A433%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520a%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A22%25253A483)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520Q.bootstrap%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A23%25253A218)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A314%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520n%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A322)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520g%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A92)%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A37%25253A261%25250A%252520%252520%252520%252520at%252520n%252520(https%25253A%25252F%25252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%25252Fajax%25252Flibs%25252Fangular.js%25252F1.4.1%25252Fangular.min.js%25253A7%25253A322)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A416%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A38%253A15%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A92)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A261%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A92)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A37%253A261%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520n%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangular.js%252F1.4.1%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:6:416%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:38:15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:37:92)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:37:261%0A%20%20%20%20at%20n%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:7:322)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:37:92)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20db%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:40:367)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(https:%2F%2Fcdnjs.cloudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.1%2Fangular.min.js:19:219) *(Failed to instantiate module protonApp due to...)* and don't know how to track the problem down (I'm new to angular)

The

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    ...
}());
```

I have round the code is because the (little) research I have done says you should have your code between these when they are in separate files.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('protonApp',['ui.router','protonAppControllers','protonAppServices']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        ...
    }]);

    app.value('debug',true);

    app.run(function($rootScope,$state,$http,debug,LeftMenuService) {
        ...
    });
}());


(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('protonAppControllers', ['$scope','$http','LeftMenuService']);
}());


(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('protonAppServices', ['$rootScope','$http']);
}());

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('protonAppControllers').controller('loginController',['$scope','$http','$state',function($scope,$http,$state){
        ...
    }]);
}());

(function () {
    angular.module('protonAppControllers').controller('surveyListController',['$scope','$http','LeftMenuService',function($scope,$http,LeftMenuService){
        ...
    }]);
}());

(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('protonAppControllers').controller('surveyHelpController',['$scope','$http','LeftMenuService',function($scope,$http,LeftMenuService){
        ...
    }]);
}());


(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('protonAppServices').service('LeftMenuService', function($http,$rootScope){
        ...
    });
}());
```

**EDIT**

Further digging reveals I can not access `$rootScope` or `$scope` inside any of my controller files

Comment: have you clicked on the error link in the console ? It might give you more informations about the cause of the error

Comment: Otherwise in your module injection you don't have to add $scope and $http : angular.module('protonAppServices', []);  Inject these in the controller but not in the module declaration

Comment: I'll remove them from the module declaration. Thanks I didn't know that

Comment: Same thing for $rootscope (every $xxx I think)

Comment: Thanks that worked!!!! Please put it in as an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: Just an extra side note, [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) is a link to an article about best practice for file structure in angular, its really interesting, since you are restructuring your files I thought I should show you a really great way.

Comment: Scratch that. While having empty brackets in `angular.module('protonAppControllers', []);` and angular.module('protonAppServices', []);` made it work as a one page app as soon as I moved these components into their separate files the errors grew :( It now has injection errors for `protoAppControllers`, `protoAppServices` & `leftMenuService` :( x 2

Comment: Thanks for the link to the article. I've read it before but I was hoping that there might be one about formatting your code in separate files and the order of your script tags in your main file (just in case either of these things affect execution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your module injection you don't have to add $scope and $http :

```
angular.module('protonAppServices', []);
```

Inject these in the controller but not in the module declaration

Answer (score 1):

1. You dont need to inject anything while declaring a module, you could use them in you controller as mentioned @ThibauDL
2. I usually prefer declaring the modules just above the angular app declaration.

I have modified your a code in [plnkr](https://jsfiddle.net/pamio/wLwoLek5/) which should give you an idea as to how the code must be organized.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('protonAppControllers', []);
  angular.module('protonAppServices', []);

  var app = angular.module('protonApp', ['ui.router', 'protonAppControllers', 'protonAppServices']);

  app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      //...
    }
  ]);

  app.value('debug', true);

  app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $http, debug, LeftMenuService) {
    //...
  });
}());


(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('protonAppServices').service('LeftMenuService', function($http, $rootScope) {
    //...
  });
}());

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('protonAppControllers').controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state',
    function($scope, $http, $state) {
      $scope.login = "Hi Please login!";
      // ...
    }
  ]);
}());

(function() {
  angular.module('protonAppControllers').controller('surveyListController', ['$scope', '$http', 'LeftMenuService',
    function($scope, $http, LeftMenuService) {
      //...
    }
  ]);
}());

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('protonAppControllers').controller('surveyHelpController', ['$scope', '$http', 'LeftMenuService',
    function($scope, $http, LeftMenuService) {
      $scope.test = "Hxxxxi";
      //...
    }
  ]);
}());
```

```html
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="protonApp">
  <div ng-controller="loginController">
    <input type="text" ng-model='login' />
  </div>
</body>
```

Also you could now place them in separate files as you wanted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the example and the explanation. I have decided to move all my code back into one page and am slowly moving things into separate file. So far I have had success with moving the controllers. I think it's just one of those things that needs to be done gradually.

Comment: A lot started to work when I move the `<script src="...">` (for the app, controllers and services) after the embedded script

Comment: I've managed to move everything into separate files apart from the main app with the routing and the run function. Not a perfect solution, but better then it was :)

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If yes then you might want to consider accepting it 

Comment: I was on mobile and did not see that an answer was already accepted. Sorry about that

Comment: No worries. Thanks for taking the time out to provide a detailed explanation. I know how long it can take to compile an answer. I appreciate it (thumbs up)